# Misleading documentation of Dailymotion events

Tags: dailymotion-api

I recently tried to add an event listener to the Dailymotion player from the javascript API by following the [documentation](https://developers.dailymotion.com/player/#events).

As I was not receiving any events, I discovered the list by doing `dailymotion.events`. This one returns me an object whose keys are in caps but not the values... the documentation shows us by an example that the events are in caps:

```
player.on("YOUR_EVENT", (state)).
```

Now that I’ve put the values in lowercase, I can hear the events of the Dailymotion player.

Answer (score 1):

We’ve recently released a new library and the API naming construction did get updated.

If you are using the latest library: `https://geo.dailymotion.com/libs/player.js`, you can benefit from the new Player API and the list of events can be seen here: https://developers.dailymotion.com/player/#events

Please see example code: `https://codepen.io/team/dailymotion-developer/pen/VwzpLXq`
If you are using the legacy SDK, `https://api.dmcdn.net/all.js` please be aware we are in the process of discontinuing support for this product and advise you to adapt our newer technology.

However, in the meantime, the list of legacy events can be found here. https://developers.dailymotion.com/player/#player-api-events

Comment: Precisely, this is what I tell you in my message, your documentation for your "new library" is misleading. It is from this [`https://geo.dailymotion.com/libs/player/`](https://geo.dailymotion.com/libs/player/) url that I get the Dailymotion player. And it is from this [`https://developers.dailymotion.com/player/#events`](https://developers.dailymotion.com/player/#events) documentation that I build my event listener.
The documentation indicates that the events are capitalized when in reality they are keys for the `window.dailymotion.events` object.